# removing @, $ from comma-separated string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query

```
declare @strString varchar(500)
set @strString ='Terminal$Attr1,Attr2,Attr3,Attr4,Attr5,Attr6,@Connector$Con1,Con2,Con3,Con4,@Wire$W1,W2,W3,W4,W5,' 

;WITH StrCTE(start, stop) AS
    (
      SELECT  1, CHARINDEX('$' , @strString )
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  stop + 1, CHARINDEX(',' ,@strString  , stop + 1)
      FROM StrCTE
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT   SUBSTRING(@strString , start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END) AS stringValue
    FROM StrCTE
    where SUBSTRING(@strString , start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END)<>''
```

which is providing me the output :

```
stringValue
Terminal  
Attr1  
Attr2  
Attr3  
Attr4  
Attr5  
Attr6   
@Connector$Con1  
Con2  
Con3  
Con4  
@Wire$W1  
W2  
W3  
W4  
W5
```

but I need the output as :

```
stringValue  
Terminal  
Attr1  
Attr2  
Attr3  
Attr4  
Attr5  
Attr6  
Connector  
Con1  
Con2  
Con3  
Con4  
Wire  
W1  
W2  
W3  
W4  
W5
```

Comment: Seems to me that the true requirement is to remove the '@' token and to split on the '$' token, if this shows all the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this made changes in `CTE`

```
declare @strString varchar(500)
set @strString ='Terminal$Attr1,Attr2,Attr3,Attr4,Attr5,Attr6,@Connector$Con1,Con2,Con3,Con4,@Wire$W1,W2,W3,W4,W5,' 

Set @strString=REPLACE(REPLACE(@strString,'$',','),'@','')--Added

;WITH StrCTE(start, stop) AS

(
  SELECT  1, CHARINDEX(',' , @strString )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  stop + 1, CHARINDEX(',' ,@strString  , stop + 1)
  FROM StrCTE
  WHERE stop > 0
)  
SELECT   SUBSTRING(@strString , start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END) AS stringValue
FROM StrCTE
where SUBSTRING(@strString , start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END)<>''
```

Answer (score 0):

use replace( < >  , '@' , '')

```
SELECT   REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@strString , start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 4000 END, '@', '') AS stringValue
```